# iframes and transition effect multiplication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Hello I have the following script for a transition effect between iframes.
I am no fan of iframes but for my app I found it to be the best possible solution since within the iframe I can do forms, javascript events and triggers onload (which I think it can't be done if I do an AJAX of the page and put the contents inside a div, at least I tried and hasn't worked).

Anyway I was fooling around this working code trying to make it better, and by that I mean making the iframe page load faster by trying it to use some of the parent scripts and css without having to call them every time inside the iframe (if you have a solution for that one too, it would be great)

Anyway here is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyUrl = "";
    function transition(url) {
        MyUrl = url;
        window.$('#Frame').attr('src', MyUrl);
        window.$('#darkBack').slideDown('fast', function () {
            window.$('#Frame').fadeOut('fast', function () {                                
                window.$('#Frame').load(function () {
                    window.$('#Frame').fadeIn('fast', function () {
                        window.$('#darkBack').slideUp('fast', function () {                                            
                           alert('1');
                           //window.$("#Frame").contents().find("#contenido").find("form").find('input:text:enabled:first').focus();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

on the body of the parent i have something like this:

```
<div id="darkBack" style="display: none;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" height="100%" width="100%">                    
                <div id="processing">
                    process
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<iframe id="Frame" src="" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

As I said this code is working, every time I do a page change, I call the function `parent.transition("some url");` but fiddling with this code and adding the "alert" I can see that every time I call the trasnsition function the alert is displayed as much times as times the function has been called in the "history" of the clicks.

I manage to reproduce on issue the jsfiddle page on this:

https://jsfiddle.net/zsjc5spg/

Now, I am no javascript mega-expert but I am pretty sure that with in my app in about five minutes at least this function is called 20 times, and after some hour of working/navigating within the app, this script is called some couple hundred or more times.(i have tried on FF and chrome, same issue) So this MUST be slowing down the users experience after some time, anyway this useless repetition it's not helping me do some other stuff I need.

Please I need some help, maybe refining the code, maybe doing it some other way.

Thanks

The question would be, I need to clean/change the code in order to stop the multiple "runs" of the function as shown from the multiple time the alert shows up.

Comment: Not certain what Question is ?

Comment: I just changed the line `window.$('#Frame').load(function () {`for `window.$('#Frame').ready(function () {`and the multiple alterts disappeared. BUT WHYYY? Also I don't like this solution because the "ready" state is done way before the page finishes loading, therefore the "processing" transition is removed before the new page is finish, and i that case there is no need for a transition effect.

Comment: o sorry the question would be, I need to clean/change the code in order to stop the multiple runs of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `data-*` attribute to store url , `.click()` attached to `a` elements , setting `src` at `.fadeOut()` complete callback , `.ready()`

`html`

```
<div id="darkBack" style="display: none;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" height="100%" width="100%">
                <div id="processing">processing</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<iframe id="xaaxFrame" src="" scrolling="yes"></iframe> <a href="#" data-url="https://jsfiddle.net">jsfiddle</a>  <a href="#" data-url="https://example.com">example.com</a>
```

`js`

```
window.transition = function (url) {
    $("#darkBack").slideDown("fast", function () {
        $('#xaaxFrame').fadeOut("fast", function () {
            $(this).attr('src', url)
            .ready(function () {
                $('#darkBack').slideUp('fast', function () {
                    $('#xaaxFrame').fadeIn('fast', function () {
                        alert('1');
                    });
                })
            })
        })
    });

};

$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).data("url");
    window.transition(url)
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zsjc5spg/2/

Comment: Yea, without changing too much I went for the .ready() solution, which is pretty much what you are suggesting. Thanks